# Query on many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, mysql

I need help to create a query over a pilot table between two table having a many-to-many relationship. Having the following database scheme:
[image: database scheme]

I need to get, for example: the speed from the specifics table where a specific_id from specifics_intervals is related to 3 interval_id (3 differents row: (49, 37), (49, 38), (49, 39)). And... I can't figure out the way to make such a query. I hope I managed to make things clear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the query that demonstrates your best attempt. Then explain what results you are getting versus what results you expect to get. Also, please tag the specific type of sql you're using.

Comment: Start with two JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Specific Intervals" table is what's often called an "intersection table". It resolves the many-to-many by sitting between those two tables. Now, what you don't indicate is whether or not you need speed from a Session PoV or a Interval PoV. I assume Interval because that's where the MtM relation is.

The next problem here is how you wish to filter this data. We'll assume you want to get Specific Speed by Interval Duration. If so, the query is resolved like this:

```
SELECT s.speed
FROM Specifics_Intervals si 
INNER JOIN Specifics s 
ON s.Id = si.Specifics_Id 
INNER JOIN Intervals i 
ON i.Id = si.Interval_Id 
WHERE i.duration = X
```

In this case, you're using the existing 1tM relations in your intersection table to correctly resolve the MtM relationship between your two tables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not being accurate enough, I want the speed from the specifics table (interval PoV, as you said). I actually want to get the specific speed where there are 3 specific parts of a session (intervals), and those intervals are of: 1. distance 3, order 0 2. distance 2, order 1, 3. ditance 1, order 2. Which means : a first interval of 3 km, a second of 2 km and a third of 1 km. Thank you for your help! I'm pretty new in many-to-many relationships.

Comment: No worries. You'll get comfortable with MtM if you use it enough. It only takes time. That said, the answer to your final question is in the WHERE clause. You've identified three "cases" of distance and order. Just replace i.duration with a filter for each case you need.

Comment: Thank you for encouraging me! According to what you told me, I ended up having that the following query (which returns me nothing): SELECT s.speed
FROM specifics_intervals si
INNER JOIN specifics s ON s.id = si.specific_id
INNER JOIN intervals i ON i.id = si.interval_id
WHERE (i.distance = 3 AND i.interval_order = 0) AND (i.distance = 2 AND i.interval_order = 1) AND (i.distance = 1 AND i.interval_order = 2)

Comment: You need to mind your booleans. :) Where (x = 1 and y = 2) AND (x = 3 and y = 4) will never return anything because x can never simultaneously be 1 & 3. You need an OR. Where (x = 1 & y = 2) OR (x = 3 & y = 4) should get your job done.

Comment: Thank you! I must be missing something, I am lost...  If I use an OR, a single condition of the WHERE clause needs to be true to return something. But I actually need to have these 3 conditions to be true for the query to return what I want. For the specific part of a session, I need 3 differents row (intervals) to be linked to it (by distance and interval_order). Which means I must have multiple instance of intervals, I guess. Am I right? 

Comment: Would joining 3 times over the same table work? Doesn't it manipulate too many data at once?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you here. Maybe I'm not understanding. If you use the OR and if all conditions/cases exist in the DB, all should be returned. You're querying a set of data to return three rows, correct? When you do the WHERE clause, it is applied one row at a time, so a single row cannot be true for all cases at the same time. You need the OR to see if each equal to this row or that row or the other row.